# Why am I getting a runtime error 9, subscript on the following code?

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating code to open a template file and scroll through all lines in my current active workbook to find all instances of data to copy it to the template.  There are several spreadsheets in this current active workbook and there is data on each spreadsheet that needs to be copied to a different area on the template.

In my code, I have 'Dim'd each workbook and spreadsheet, including the template, and in this code I'm trying to 'set' the spreadsheets in my current workbook so I can loop through the rows and find the correct lines to copy to the template.  The error is showing on the last line of this code.  Please see my text below:

```vb
Sub NewFormPerSchool()

Dim wbTarget As Workbook
Dim wbCurrent As Workbook
Dim Ws1 As Worksheet
Dim Ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Ws3 As Worksheet
Dim Ws4 As Worksheet
Dim Ws5 As Worksheet

Set wbCurrent = ActiveWorkbook
Set wbTarget = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\cpa549\Desktop\VBA\Wendie\6.9\Working\TEMPLATE.xlsx")
Set Ws1 = wbCurrent.Worksheets("SCHOOLS")`
```

I have tried specifying the worksheet as in the current workbook, but have also tried without specifying current workbook, but on the first 'Set' line I am receiving the error.  I have tried searching through stackoverflow, and other forums, as well as through google search.

Comment: So your `wbCurrent` does not have a worksheet named `"SCHOOLS"`.

Comment: But it does. That's why I'm confused.  I even made sure that it is all uppercase spelling.  The only difference is the worksheet doesn't have the "" of course.

Comment: It evidently does not. You are not thinking that `wbCurrent` is the `C:\Users\...\TEMPLATE.xlsx`, right?

Comment: No, that template only has one sheet, sheet 1.

Comment: Great. So `wbCurrent`, which is the workbook that happened to be active right before you ordered the opening of TEMPLATE.xlsx, does not have a worksheet called `"SCHOOLS"`.

Comment: That workbook does have the SCHOOLS tab/worksheet.  The template has only one worksheet named Sheet 1

Comment: Insert before the `Open` line: `For Each w In wbCurrent.Worksheets : MsgBox "'" & w.Name & "'" : Next`.

Comment: I did that and now it opens the first 3 of them and then I get the error on the third line of code which is the same but just a different spreadsheet? Maybe I shouldn't have them all 'Set' together?     <Set wbCurrent = ActiveWorkbook
For Each w In wbCurrent.Worksheets: MsgBox "'" & w.Name & "'": Next
Set wbTarget = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\cpa549\Desktop\VBA\Wendie\6.9\Working\TEMPLATE.xlsm")
Set Ws1 = wbCurrent.Worksheets("SCHOOLS")
Set Ws2 = wbCurrent.Worksheets("CARES")
Set Ws3 = wbCurrent.Worksheets("CRSSA")
Set Ws4 = wbCurrent.Worksheets("ARP")>

Comment: It's not clear what is the three things being opened. You are only opening one file here (which is named `TEMPLATE.xlsx` in your original question and `TEMPLATE.xlsm` in your comment). Please edit your question to show the actual current code and the actual line where the error actually happens. Please include the output of the `MsgBox` thingie. You may replace the MsgBox with `Debug.Print`.

Comment: I'm so sorry to have bothered you.  I'm not sure what you did in that string that fixed it, but now I'm not having the issue.  I'm still new to this so it takes me forever to write the code and sometimes the smallest things confuse me.

Comment: Where is this code located? In `wbCurrent` or some other workbook?

Comment: The code is located in wbCurrent.

Comment: Then you most definitely need to use `Dim wbCurrent As Workbook: Set wbCurrent = ThisWorkbook` where `ThisWorkbook` refers to the workbook containing this code. `ActiveWorkbook` is used very rarely when there is no other option.